# How to sort array of objects have date properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

I have an array :

```
    const arr = [
      { name: 'abc', date: '30/03/2014' },
      { name: 'cde', date: '30/03/2015' },
      { name: 'fgh', date: '20/04/2014' },
      { name: 'xyz', date: '17/09/2014' },
    ];
```

How can I sort this array so that the output would be like this:

```
    const arr = [
      { name: 'cde', date: '30/03/2015' },
      { name: 'xyz', date: '17/09/2014' },
      { name: 'fgh', date: '20/04/2014' },
      { name: 'abc', date: '30/03/2014' },
    ];
```

// sort the array with date in latest first.

Comment: [Results from Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sort+by+date+string&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBR711BR711&oq=js+how+to+sortb+by+date+st&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.5669j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: you have to set the date format to "YYYY-MM-DD" then you can compare directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with your own sorting comperator. For this `split` the dates and build with taht in the right sequence a `new Date` which can be compared.

```js
    const arr = [
      { name: 'abc', date: '30/03/2014' },
      { name: 'cde', date: '30/03/2015' },
      { name: 'fgh', date: '20/04/2014' },
      { name: 'xyz', date: '17/09/2014' },
    ];
    
    arr.sort((a,b) => {
        let tempA = a.date.split('/');
        let tempB = b.date.split('/');
        return ((new Date(tempB[2],tempB[1],tempB[0])) - (new Date(tempA[2],tempA[1],tempA[0])));
    });
    
    console.log(arr);
```